# Jquery, How to make smooth jump animation?

Tags: jquery

I make a game which is there's a ball and some blocks to hold that ball from falling. I use setInterval method to make the gravitation for the ball

```
setInterval(function(){
ball.offset({top: ballMoveY += gravitation});
$("p").html(ballMoveX + '<br>' + ballMoveY + '<br><br>' + blokPos + '<br><br>' + gravitation);
if (ballMoveY > blok4Y+20){alert('game over'); return ballMoveY = 0; return ballMoveX = 0};
if ((ballMoveY == blok1Y && ballMoveX < blok1X && ballMoveX > 2) ||
    (ballMoveY == blok2Y && ballMoveX < blok2X && ballMoveX > 15) || 
    (ballMoveY == blok3Y && ballMoveX < blok3X && ballMoveX > 110) || 
    (ballMoveY == blok4Y && ballMoveX < blok4X && ballMoveX > 325)){

    return gravitation = 0; 
}
else {return gravitation = 5;};
}, 5);
```

But I can't make the jump to be smooth. The jumping is start from the top point, not animate from bottom then up and then fall.  I use spacebar keyup to trigger the ball to jump, and arrow keys to move the ball right and left.
This is the jumping code:

```
$(window).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.which === 32 && gravitation == 0){
        return gravitation -= 200;
    }
})
```

Here's the full code https://jsfiddle.net/b2orwnrz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gravity is basically the rate of change of speed in time, so in order to simulate gravity, you would have to add a `speed` variable to your system. This speed would be changing according to `gravity`, and the `speed` would be used to change `position` of your object.
And a jump is a instantaneous change of speed in a direction opposite to gravity.

Working that way would allow you to create a smooth jump effect, but would require you to modify a bit the rest of your code. But something like this should give you ideas:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        var ball = $("#ball");
        ballPos = ball.position();
        ballMoveX = ballPos.left;
        ballMoveY = ballPos.top;
        gravitation = 3, speed = 0; //You declare speed as well as gravitation. Setting speed to 0 is the equivalent of dropping a ball without any force.

        var blok1 = $("#blok1").offset();
        blok1Y = blok1.top;
        blok1X = parseInt(blok1.left) + parseInt($("#blok1").css("width"));
        var blok2 = $("#blok2").offset();
        blok2Y = blok2.top;
        blok2X = parseInt(blok2.left) + parseInt($("#blok2").css("width"));
        var blok3 = $("#blok3").offset();
        blok3Y = blok3.top;
        blok3X = parseInt(blok3.left) + parseInt($("#blok3").css("width"));
        var blok4 = $("#blok4").offset();
        blok4Y = blok4.top;
        blok4X = parseInt(blok4.left) + parseInt($("#blok4").css("width"));

        blokPos = blok1Y + '<br>' + blok2Y + '<br>' + blok3Y + '<br>' + blok4Y + '<br>' + '<br>' + blok1X + '<br>' + blok2X + '<br>' + blok3X + '<br>' + blok4X;


        setInterval(function () {
            speed += gravitation; //The speed changes according to the gravitation. 
                                  //You can modulate the speed at which this rate changes by changing gravitation value. 
                                 //But if you want to stay close to reality, gravitation should be constant.
            ball.offset({
                top: ballMoveY += speed // The position changes according to speed. 
                                        //Speed is basically difference of position in time. 
                                        //Since this difference of time is taken care of with setInterval, 
                                        //you set difference of position directly with speed.
            });
            $("p").html(ballMoveX + '<br>' + ballMoveY + '<br><br>' + blokPos + '<br><br>' + speed);
            if (ballMoveY > blok4Y + 20) {
                alert('game over');
                return ballMoveY = 0;
                return ballMoveX = 0
            };
            //Since your position values are less precise than before you need 
            //to validate if they're greater than, not equal. 
            //You'll see that for now, this makes a strange effect of 
            //stopping the ball not exactly at the right place.
            if ((ballMoveY > blok1Y && ballMoveX < blok1X && ballMoveX > 2) || (ballMoveY > blok2Y && ballMoveX < blok2X && ballMoveX > 15) || (ballMoveY > blok3Y && ballMoveX < blok3X && ballMoveX > 110) || (ballMoveY > blok4Y && ballMoveX < blok4X && ballMoveX > 325)) {
                speed = 0; // IF ball is on block its speed gets back to 0
                gravitation = 0;// Here, normally it should stop movement, not change the gravity, 
                                //but this can be done this way. But if you were the refactorfurther, 
                                //you should clear the interval when the ball is stopped 
                                //and start it on keydown callback.
                return speed = 0;// Not sure you need to return anything...
            } else {
                return gravitation = 3;
            };
        }, 50);




        $(window).keydown(function (e) {
            if (e.which === 39) {
                ball.offset({
                    left: ballMoveX += 5
                });
            }
            if (e.which === 37) {
                ball.offset({
                    left: ballMoveX -= 5
                });
            }


        })

        $(window).keyup(function (e) {
            console.log(e.which, gravitation);
            if (e.which === 32 && gravitation == 0) {
                return  speed = -30;// That's where your jump happens. A jump is a force in up direction. 
                                    //A one time force will have the effect of changing the speed on one moment. 
                                    //Once the speed has changed, the gravitation continues to have 
                                    //an effect and makes the ball slow down, then fall.
            }
        })

    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3rfpL420/4/

Comment: you wrote a from-scratch game engine for a one vote answer, that is dedication. have an upvote. I used this in researching a concept for a CSS game engine, solid stuff here. Your collision detection is wonky, but you make mention of that in the comments. solid work!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to create your own functions you can use the animate function provided by jQuery for example:

```
$('#ball').animate({'bottom':20}, bouncetime, 'easeInQuad');
```

I've created an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xtggqcg5/1/

For the easing I'm using the easeInQuad that's available through jQuery UI but you can add your own easing function.

Comment: thanks for the answer,,but I know animate method, i've tried it, but it didn't work in this case, because there's gravity.. the ball is already animated from top to bottom, start from the DOM ready, and I want to make it jump.

Comment: Well that's the beauty about the easing system. You can create your own and take gravity into account.